# Entity Framework and self referencing table

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, guid

I have a table that self references to create a hierarchy.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Topics](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentTopicID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Topics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([ID] ASC)
    WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
    ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Topics]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Topics_Topics] 
FOREIGN KEY([ParentTopicID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Topics] ([ID])
```

For the "root" nodes, the `ParentTopicID` will be null, and children will point to appropriate `TopicID`.

This structure works in SQL but Entity Framework appears to be having problems with this. Even if I try a simple enumeration such as:

```
foreach(var t in container.Topics) {
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

I get an error:

> The 'ParentTopicID' property on 'Topic' could not be set to a 'null'
>   value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Guid'.

The second problem is to query this table to find the root nodes or children of a particular topic.

In SQL, it would be simple as `Where ParentTopicID is null` but since Guid is not null in .Net, Linq syntax complains and doesn't find any matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the problem here is your problem has NULL specified for the ParentTopicID but in EF Designer you probably have ParentTopicID set to nullable false. Change that first and we can go from there if it doesn't fix it.

In the designer, select the class, select ParentTopicID, press F4 for properties.

Comment: I tried but that results in the following error:

Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Topic' in relationship 'FK_Topics_Topics'. Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '0..1'

Comment: That's fine. It just means that you have a relationship which is set to 1..1 instead of 0..1. You need to change the end point of the relationship so it says something like one topic can have 0 or 1 topics.

Comment: Never mind, your original suggestion worked. I rebuilt the model and then applied your suggestion and I am not getting any compile or runtime errors. Thanks a ton.